# Making VBA script run faster

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

For the first time I've worked in Excel VBA to find rows in my dataset that contain the same adress as another entry in a cluster. These entries have to be merged and the row then is deleted. I've come up with the following, which works (As far as I can tell from the testing I did on small samples of the set):

```
Sub Merge_Orders()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim y As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

For i = 2 To lastrow //for each row, starting below header row
  j = 1
  y = (Cells(i, 9)) //this is the clusternumber
  Do While y = (Cells(i + j, 9)) //while the next row is in the same cluster
    x = (Cells(i, 12)) //this is the adresscode
    k = 1
    Do While x = (Cells(i + k, 12)) //while the current adresscode is the same as the next, iterating until another adresscode is hit
      Cells(i, 16) = Val(Cells(i, 16)) + Val(Cells(i + k, 16)) //update cell value
      Cells(i, 18) = Cells(i, 18) + Cells(i + k, 18)  //update cell value
      Cells(i, 19) = Cells(i, 19) + Cells(i + k, 19)  //update cell value
      If Cells(i, 20) > Cells(i + k, 20) Then
        Cells(i, 20) = Cells(i + k, 20)  //update cell value
      End If
      If Cells(i, 21) > Cells(i + k, 21) Then
        Cells(i, 21) = Cells(i + k, 21)  //update cell value
      End If
      Cells(i, 22) = Cells(i, 22) + Cells(i + k, 22)  //update cell value
      Cells(i, 23) = Cells(i, 23) + Cells(i + k, 23)  //update cell value

      Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete //Delete the row from which data was pulled
      k = k + 1
    Loop
    j = j + 1
  Loop
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
End Sub
```

The problem I'm facing is time. Testing this on a small sample of ~50 rows took over 5 minutes. My entries total over 100K rows. It's been running for over a day with no end in sight. Is there a way to optimize this so I don't have to wait until I'm grey?

Kind regards,

Rob

Comment: Do you have any things being calculated in cells? If so, placing these lines at the top and on at the bottom, respectively, might help: `Application.Calculation=xlManual` and `Application.Calculation=xlAutomatic`

Comment: I assume the `//` are comments you added for SO, not in the code itself? (because `'` is the comment marker for VBA). If you step through the code with `F8`, where does the loop seem to get stuck? Also possibly add some breaks in each part of the loop to help figure where the loop is taking more time than expected.

Comment: If your code works as intended (performance aside - test it with a small data set to be sure), then the best place to ask for feedback and optimization tips is on [codereview.se], not [so].

Comment: Mat's Mug, I will go there then, thank you. As i stated the code seems to work as intended.

Comment: Can this code be rewritten as an SQL statement? You can use ADODB to connect to an Excel worksheet and issue `SELECT` statements against it using a Recordset object. You can then copy the recordset back into the worksheet.

Comment: You problem will be due to the `Do While y` and `Do While x` loops continuing "forever" once `Cells(i, 9)` or `Cells(i, 12)` are `Empty` (which will happen once `i` reaches a completely empty row, which will happen because you are deleting rows but still looping through to what was the last row number **before** you deleted anything).  You could try changing your loop to be `For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1`.  I haven't analysed what you are doing enough to determine whether that will give you any other issues, but it should get rid of the problem caused by comparisons against empty cells.

Comment: Or you could possibly just add a statement saying `If IsEmpty(Cells(i, "A")) Then Exit For` immediately after the `For i = 2 To lastrow` statement.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Hah, the reason I'm working in VBA is because I couldn't my excel files imported into MySQL due to an unknown error in the spreadsheet!

Comment: Another option is to read the data into a 2-dimensional array using `Range.Value`, making the modifications in memory, and writing back the data again using `Range.Value`. The benefit of both of these is that you avoid unneeded calls to `Cells` and other Automation properties and methods.

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you very much, will test this as soon as I get the chance. As for your last comment, I suspect that loading into an array will reduce the load times significantly due to a lot less callbacks to the worksheet. Going to try that asap

Comment: You might be able to fix the errors using SQL against the Excel spreadsheet, before trying to import the data into MySQL.

Comment: One of the biggest performance increases you'll see is if you add the data to an array, rather than writing it directly to each cell. Once your array is populated, write the full array at once to the worksheet. This works for multi-dimensional arrays too

Comment: Can't you just replace the k with J? You don't need to increment k because you are deleting the row.

Comment: @dashnick yes you are right. I doubt it will change much in the way of the performance though.

Comment: Also the lastrow thing is bad because the rows gets deleted. Maybe just check if the row is blank?

Comment: @dashnick could you clarify? You mean lastrow becomes a number and the script finishes far before it hits that number?

Comment: You could just write the data into a VBA array in a single line of code. Delete the data in the spreadsheet. Then, using pure VBA construct a new array which you then write to the spreadsheet in a single line of code. All those `Cell()` calls are expensive. Think of the worksheet as a client and VBA as the server. You don't writer server-side code which constantly sends individual numbers to and from the client.

Answer (score 1):

Two things as I mentioned in the comments:

1) Remove `k` (and the entire `k=k+1` line); replace with `j`.  Also replace your `Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Delete` with `Rows(i + j).EntireRow.Delete`.

2) Since you are deleting rows, `lastrow` is actually blank by the time you get there.  Instead of `i=2 to lastrow`, make it `do while Cells(i,12)<>""` or something.  This is causing it to loop over a bunch of rows that are empty.

Also, you can do these type of rollups much easier with a PivotTable, or, as mentioned in the comments, with an SQL `GROUP BY`.